# Is it possible for a partially applied function to call its partially applied self?

Tags: scala, akka, currying, partial-application

I've started playing with Akka and have found that most of my actors have part immutable state and part mutable state. Both could be merged into a `State` case class which could then be copied on solely its mutable state and passed back into `apply` to update the `Behavior`.

However, it'd be magical if that wasn't necessary. Is it possible for a partially applied Scala function to somehow recursively call itself, but starting at its 2nd parameter list? Rather than starting the entire chain from the beginning?

```scala
sealed trait Command
final case class AddA() extends Command
final case class AddB() extends Command

def apply(
  immutableState1: String,
  immutableState2: String,
  immutableState3: String
)(
  mutableState: List[String] = Nil
): Behavior[Command] = Behaviors.receiveMessage {

  // without respecifying all immutable state:
  case AddA() => CallIts2ndParamList("A" :: mutableState)

  // what I'm trying to avoid:
  case AddB() => apply(
    immutableState1,
    immutableState2,
    immutableState3
  )("B" :: mutableState)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, maybe I was looking for solutions in the wrong area. A nested function should do the trick actually!

```
  sealed trait Command
  final case class AddA() extends Command
  final case class AddB() extends Command

  def apply(
      immutableState1: String,
      immutableState2: String,
      immutableState3: String
  ): Behavior[Command] = {
    def nestedApply(mutableState: List[String]): Behavior[Command] =
      Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case AddA() => nestedApply("A" :: mutableState)
      }
    nestedApply(Nil)
  }
```